# @Transactional not working with readOnly = true

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have following code, where I am setting `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`.

Code in `main()` method:

```
    ApplicationContext context = Utils.getContext();
    AnnotatedCrudDao service = new AnnotatedCrudDao();
    DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) context.getBean("mySqlDataSource");
    service.setDataSource(dataSource);
    service.insert(account, user, movie);


@Transactional
public class AnnotatedCrudDao extends JdbcDaoSupport {

    private static Logger logger;

    static {
    logger = Logger.getLogger(AnnotatedCrudDao.class);
    }


    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public void insert(Account account, User user, MovieTicket movie) {

    TicketUtils.insertAccount(getJdbcTemplate(), account);
    TicketUtils.insertUser(getJdbcTemplate(), user);
    TicketUtils.insertMovie(getJdbcTemplate(), movie);
    }
}

class TicketUtils{

    public static void insertUser(JdbcTemplate template, User user) {
    String queryUser = "INSERT INTO t_user_txn (ID, NAME, ACCOUNT_ID, TICKETID) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    logger.debug("queryUser" + queryUser);
    template.update(queryUser, new Object[] { user.getId(), user.getName(),
    user.getAccount().getId(), user.getTicketId() });
    }

    public static void insertMovie(JdbcTemplate template, MovieTicket movie) {
    String queryMovie = "INSERT INTO t_movieticket_txn (ID, MOVIENAME, TOTALTICKETSCOUNT, PRICE) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    logger.debug("queryMovie:" + queryMovie);
    template.update(queryMovie, new Object[] { movie.getId(),
    movie.getMovieName(), movie.getTotalTicketsCount(),
    movie.getPrice() });
    }

    public static void insertAccount(JdbcTemplate template, Account account) {
    String queryAccount = "INSERT INTO t_account_txn (ID, AMOUNT) VALUES (?,?)";
    logger.debug("queryAccount:" + queryAccount);
    template.update(queryAccount, new Object[] { account.getId(),
    account.getAmount() });
    }

}
```

**Context:**

```
    <bean id="mySqlDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:qadb7"/>
    <property name="username" value="tp2"/>
    <property name="password" value="tp2"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dsTxnMgr" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mySqlDataSource" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Add this tag to enable annotations transactions -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="dsTxnMgr" />
```

Even thought I have set `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` for insert method, still the insert operation is being performed. Should not the attribute `readOnly`, which is set to `true` should take care that insert cannot be performed on this method.

Comment: Is never a good idea to add @Transactional to the entire class. Read more here: https://codete.com/blog/5-common-spring-transactional-pitfalls/

Answer (score 4):

A couple of things

1. You are creating your own instance of the dao, this isn't spring managed and therefor nothing is being done with the `@Transactional` annotation.
2. `readonly="true"` enforces nothing don't expect an exception to be thrown or inserts not to happen, very few jdbc providers actually do something with the `readOnly` flag. It is merely a hint to the underlying system nothing more nothing less. In general it is used and understood by ORM tools like Hibernate and the like. But for plain JDBC access in the majority of cases it is simply ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating the `AnnotatedCrudDao` object yourself. As such, Spring cannot process it and add `@Transactional` behavior.

```
AnnotatedCrudDao service = new AnnotatedCrudDao();
```

Let Spring manage your object. Declare a `<bean>` element for it in your context and use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place a `@Repository` annotation to make it working

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class AnnotatedCrudDao extends JdbcDaoSupport {
```

Comment: Make sure to add package scan to include a bean to the application context.